# How to set focus to a button widget programmatically?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-button

Is it possible to set a focus to a button widget which lies somewhere down in my layout? `onCreate` of the activity my control/focus should be on that button programmatically.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Yeah it's possible.

```
Button myBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButtonId);
myBtn.requestFocus();
```

or in XML

```
<Button ...><requestFocus /></Button>
```

**Important Note:** The button widget needs to be `focusable` *and* `focusableInTouchMode`. Most widgets are `focusable` but not `focusableInTouchMode` by default. So make sure to either set it in code

```
myBtn.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

or in XML

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: I trying it in onCreate method but its not working. I am creating buttons dynamically and adding the buttons in LinearLayout. Can any one please help me out?

Comment: it does not worked for me. I have an EditView in my page that always gets focus.

Comment: `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` required to click a button twice, the first click to set focus, the second click to make action. This is not appropriate for common flow.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
btn.requestFocusFromTouch();
```